# Meaning of SCOPE tag in Maven Dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies

When we use scope tag while providing dependencies in POM file of Maven, we can give several valid values (compile, run, provided etc..). I understand that  tag is applicable for only transitive dependencies (i.: list of JARs required by direct dependencies that we give in POM).

When we give the scope as provided, will the dependency not be downloaded from Maven central repository ? Can someone please confirm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies with scope `provided` are meant to be provided by the container in which the application runs (e.g. provided by jboss).

This means that they are downloaded by Maven, put on the compile and test classpath, but not included into the final WAR or EAR you are building.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time to look into my question.